# WindowsPower shell script not working as expecting

Tags: shell, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Hi all I have script which need to delete older then 90 days files.issue is without time calculation for 90 days script working fine.if we add when condition to check time frame ex: 90 days its not working.

I have specific folder which containing sub-folders below script not deleting files under sub-folders script deleting files only specified folder its deleting sub-folder files.

we have requirement power shell script which should delete files older then 90 days files and it should delete files under subfolders also.

Can any one suggest any changes need to do for below script

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\samples\" -Include *.* -Recurse -Force | where CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-10) | foreach {$_.Delete()}
```

Comment: Are you getting any output when you enter `Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\samples\" -Include *.*  -Recurse -Force | where {$_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-10)}`? You should get every file that is older than 10 Days...

Comment: I am not seeing any output.and   folder D:\samples\test having around 60 files with different type of extensions like XML,.log etc and almost all files are old files only.

Comment: How about using it with `| where {$_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-10)}`? The `-gt` should cause it to show all files that have been created in the last 10 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your usage of several powershell tags (which normally exclude each other) is ambiguous,
if you want to ensure the script is runnable under PSv2 use only that tag.

The `Remove-Item` cmdlet directly accepts piped input, so I'd use it instead of a ForEach-Object and the objects `.delete()` method.

The `-File` parameter requires PSv3+ , the alternative is to check for (not=`!`) `$_.PSIsContainer`

The script is IMO easier to read breaking lines where PowerShell expects a continuation and indenting:

```
## Q:\Test\2019\01\22\SO_54311383.ps1
$BasePath = "D:\samples\*"
$Treshold = (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-10)

Get-ChildItem -Path $BasePath -Recurse -Force |
    Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer -and
                  $_.CreationTime -lt $Treshold} |
        Remove-Item  -WhatIf # -Force
```

If the output looks OK, remove the `-WhatIf` in the last line.
The eventually neccessary `-Force` parameter is commented out for the moment.

Comment: Hi Thanks for quick reply i tried above script its not deleting files i tried changing path giving subfolder as well but not deleting any files

Comment: Hi i Identified one thing if i test with same folder multiple times its not deleting files. suppose If i use same folder to test the script its not deleting files if i give some other path its working fine seems some script holding cache memory can we have any fix for this. becoz if i put in real time in DEV or SIT it will not becoz we will have same path for everyday trigger so if any fix can you please let me know thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your `| where` needs curly brackets `{}`. The object is refered to by  `$_`. Using that, your code would look like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\samples\" -file -Recurse -Force | where {$_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-10)} | foreach {$_.Delete()}
```

Note: I replaced `-Include "."` with `-file` to include all files. This requires at least version 3.0 of powershell. Check the Version with `$Host`

Comment: Hi , no luck not deleting any files :(

Comment: Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\samples\test" -file -Recurse -Force | where {$_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-5)} | foreach {$_.Delete()}   i tried above script as well but not working the folder contains different kind of files like .log,.txt, etc but no files deleted